# how to force a collection of inputs to always have the same value when typing in them?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm looking for a method to give the same value to a collection of inputs when i type something on them,
lets say we have 10 of them,and i type the word "dog" to one of them,then all of them get the word "dog",then i type the word "cat" to an other one,every one gets the word "cat".

Something like this,which is not valid,but i just want to explain the logic :

```
$(document).on('input', 'input', function () {

$("#main input").each(function() {

$(this).val($(this).val())

});

});
```

Any ideas?

```css
input{
position:relative;
float:left;
clear:both;
margin-bottom:1px;
width:85px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'd do it like this but then again I haven't written jQuery for a while.

Since I assume you might have other input fields on the page I created a [data attributed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) called `data-copy` to attach our event listener. I was not inclined to do this via a class which is also totally valid mostly because its too easy to attach styles to those classes and then mix functionality and styling.
Read more about attribute selectors here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

If you want to do it without attributes you can change the selector to something like this but I would caution you to make it specific to avoid side effects.

```
$(function() {
  $('#main input').on('keyup', function() {
    const val = $(this).val();
    $('#main input').not(this).val(val);
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-copy]').on('keyup', function() {
    const val = $(this).val();
    $('[data-copy]').not(this).val(val);
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 85px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
    <input data-copy type="text">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks 
excuse my noobness but could you explain,whats data-copy in the input tag ?
its like a class ? and how do you set it without an attribute
also its the first time i see such a selector in jquery,with the square brackets,where can i find docs on this?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer